# Will indexing preserve the native schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are planning to create an index maintenance activity for an application as their fragmentation level was high but they wanted to make sure their native schema is preserved.

Please advise by scheduling maintenance (update stats, index) jobs will have any impact on schema level

Version: SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Comment: Please can you define what their worries are? What is the definition on "schema level" that you are referring to? Is it the SQL schema? Is it the overall database structure? is it schema permissions?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the phrase "native schema"

Comment: Also, what exactly is an "index *maintenance* activity?"  If you "add an index" to a table, that index simply becomes part of the table and it maintains *itself.*  Just as "the index(es) at the back of a book" do not change the book itself. Indexes only allow certain values to be easier to find.

Comment: Native schema in the sense, the schema that are created during the DB creation. They haven't performed any re-indexing or statistics update since the DB creation. So, we advised them to go for re-indexing weekly and update stats daily. So, they raised concerns if the schema structure will be changed because of re-indexing? Please advise

Comment: No the "native schema" will not be modified. But be sure to run re-undexing and updating stats not during the working hours (example during the night or weekend), the re-undexing could take long time (several hours for a big database), be aware also to do a rebuild or reorganize.